# __builtin_return_address returns the wrong address

Tags: c, gnu

I'm trying to get the address of the end of a function, so I use `__builtin_return_address` but it returns a value higher than the next declared funciton, here `main`:

```c
uintptr_t foo( void )
{
    return (uintptr_t)__builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0));
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    printf("foo:\t%zu\nmain:\t%zu\n", foo(), (uintptr_t)main);
    return (0);
}
```

output:

```
foo:    94718524985719
main:   94718524985687
```

But how is it possible ? How could main start address be lower than foo return address ?

Comment: You're getting (more or less) the end of `main`, not the end of `foo`.  Inside `foo`, the return address is the address that will be *returned to* after `foo` is done — that is, an address inside of `foo`'s caller, `main`.

Comment: ok so `__builtin_return_address(0)` returns the end of the calling function then ?

Comment: Well, no.  It'll be an address somewhere inside the calling function — typically somewhere between the beginning and the end.

Comment: `"%zu"` isn't correct for `uintptr_t`. You want `"%" PRIuPTR` (Include `inttypes.h`.)

Answer (score 2):

[`__builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) gives the address at which execution continues when the current function returns. In your snippet, this will be somewhere in `main` since the call to `foo` is in `main`.

32 bytes after the start of `main` makes sense.

When I [compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/4q3hhPvxx) your code<sup>[1]</sup>, it produced the following assembly and a difference of 26:

```
foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "foo:\t%lu\nmain:\t%lu\n"
main:
        push    rbp                           ---     <--- Address of this
        mov     rbp, rsp                       |
        push    rbx                            |
        sub     rsp, 24                        | 26 bytes
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi        |
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rsi        |
        mov     ebx, OFFSET FLAT:main          |
        call    foo                           ---
        mov     rdx, rbx                              <--- Address of this
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        leave
        ret
```

---

1. I corrected the format pattern.

   ```c
   #include <inttypes.h>

   printf("foo:\t%" PRIuPTR "\nmain:\t%" PRIuPTR "\n", foo(), (uintptr_t)main);
   ```